# Querying an array of objects in puppet

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to use the Puppet 4.4 AST to query a custom fact using the `inventory` API. The structure of the fact I'm querying is

```
apps: [
  {
    name: 'test-app-1',
    version: '1'
  },
  {
    name: 'test-app-2',
    version: '5'
  }
  ...
]
```

I'm looking to return all nodes that contain a hash of `app['name'] == 'test-app-1'`. This is close to returning what I'm looking for:

```
["=", "facts.apps[1].name", "test-app-2"]
```

but I don't know which element index the app will be at, so I need something more like this (incorrect) syntax:

```
["=", "facts.apps[*].name", "test-app-2"]
```

Comment: If you need to access the PuppetDB for info like this, have you considered using the Python API? It would be more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out using the `match` notation.

```
["=", "facts.apps.match(\".*\").name", "test-app-2"]
```